# What are the 'free to use' workload generators available for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, tools

A couple that I know about are

- http://www.dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html and
- http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/

**Are there any others?** I am looking for tools what can generate random workload (based on some parameters) that can be saved (possibly as an SQL file) and run against an Oracle 11gR2 db separately.

Answer (score 3):

Lazer,

Here are what I have found: [Load and Performance Tools](http://www.testingfaqs.org/t-load.html). This is a huge list of tools, you can find out what product is better for you, but I could not see any tool that has been created specially for Oracle databases (on my first sight). For Sql Server

[An information resource for software testers](http://www.testingfaqs.org/)

I hope it will help you.

**ADDED:**

**The best generator that you made yourself.**

Answer (score 2):

Not free (tho' Oracle 11g isn't cheap either!) but the "official" solution is [RAT](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/real-application-testing/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post the same question for SQL Server having done a bit of digging around recently.

How about the [Transaction Processing Council](http://www.tpc.org/) (TPC) workload generators?

- [TPC-E](http://www.tpc.org/tpce/egen-download-request.asp) is the latest OLTP benchmark.
- [TPC-C](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/default.asp) is the previous version of the OLTP benchmark
- [TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/default.asp) is for OLAP/DSS.

If you're inclined to dig into the code, you may be able to re-purpose [TPCCBench](http://tpccbench.codeplex.com/) which is SQL Server specific.